# what is relation between codimension and finiteness

Tags: operator-theory

I want to prove that 
Let T be a linear operator on a vector space X. If codimension of T is finite then codimension of $T^n$ is finite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actuallt you can easily proof codimension of $T^n(x)$ is less than or equal to n*codimension of T(x)